# Tensor product of group rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ be the cyclic group of integers modulo $n$. If $R\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the group ring of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ formed over $R$, then I want to compute the ring $R\mathbb{Z}_n\otimes_R R\mathbb{Z}_n$. It is known that $R\mathbb{Z}_n\simeq R[x]/(x^n-1)$ where $R[x]$ is the polynomial ring over $R$.  I guess this could help; or, maybe, there are different approaches to compute it. Could any body kindly give a help or a suitable reference?

Comment: If $G$ and $H$ are finite groups, $R[G]\otimes _RR[H]$ is canonically isomorphic to $R[G\times H]$.

Comment: Moreover, $R[x]/(f(x)) \otimes_R R[x]/(f(x)) \cong R[x,y]/(f(x),f(y))$. This follows from right exactness and the computation $R[x] \otimes_R R[x] \cong R[x,y]$.

Comment: What do you want to compute about it?

Comment: I want to know if a module  $M$ is injective over $R\mathbb{Z}_n$, is it also injective over $R\mathbb{Z}_n\otimes_R R\mathbb{Z}_n$ ?